# XGBoost (Gradient Boosting) vs Random Forest

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree, gradient-descent, xgboost, gbm

(Hope this is a right forum for this type of question, if not please kindly suggest.)

What is the performance of gradient boosting in XGBoost library versus Random Forest? Are there any benchmark numbers comparing the two?

I am about to start some work on classification and regression on many-millions events from a dataset (at least 6GB, upto TB).

Thanks

Comment: Algorithms performance can be dependent on the data, to get the best result possible you would probably try both. However, I believe XGBoost can be modified to behave as a Random Forest. In my experience the random forest implementations are not as fast as XGBoosts which may be your concern given the data size.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/vignettes/discoverYourData.html mentions how to adjust XGBoost to behave as a RF.

Answer (score 0):

You can downsample your data to a couple of MB (ok for thousands of features) and check the performance of the two algorithms.

Though, XGBoost will be more efficient for big data since efforts have been made to reduce the objective loss function to two derivatives. You may run into issues with RF with big data. Try to run RF with big data in R for instance, you will soon realize RF is not the best when coming to big data.